# Understanding どうとも思わない

Tags: grammar

> ふと、昼間の話を思い出した。
>
> 死神。自殺者さえ出している。人の死を**どうとも思わない**、──エイティシックスの。
>
> どんな、人だろうか。
>
> わたし達を、──やはり、嫌っているのだろうか。

From
86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

Does the bold part mean “indifferent to people’s death”. If it does, why does どうとも思わない mean that? How should I parse it? Are there any similar expressions?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you know how to parse the `interrogative + も + negation` pattern. For example, you can say どこへも行くな "don't go anywhere", 何も見つからなかった "could not find anything", 誰にも分からない "no one knows", 門はいつも開いてない "the gate is always closed", いつまでも忘れません "will remember this forever" and so on.

Likewise, 人の死をどうとも思わない means the subject thinks nothing about someone's death (a more literal translation is "not to regard someone's death as anything"; remember the AをBと思う pattern). 人の死を何【なん】とも思わない means the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. But I don’t quite understand why the どう in どうとも思わない literally means "anything". Doesn’t どう mean "how"? So literally どうとも思わない should mean "not to regard … as how", which doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @chinoalpha Haven't you learned that "What do you think?" is どう思う in Japanese? Please see [this](http://jpyokoso.com/dou-omou-64/) if you haven't. どう思う is a question about your opinions/thoughts themselves, not your way of thinking something.

Comment: Yes, I have learned that. I didn’t realize どうとも思わない was relevant to どう思う. There is a と(as) in どうとも思わない, which is part of the pattern AをBと思う(regard A as B), which may in turn cause me to think of the どう too literally.

Comment: @chinoalpha I see. And that reminds me, 人の死をどうも思わない  (without と) is also fine and means the same thing.